# How to use the I2C nodes with hardware sensors in node-red on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: node-red

I want to play around with some hardware sensors in node red, and therefore attached a BMP180 temperature and pressure sensor to the GPIO port of my raspberry pi as an example (works with cayenne cloud platform, so wiring is OK). I already installed some extra nodes, like node-red-contrib-i2c and node-red-contrib-brads-i2c-nodes, and I also found [this example flow](https://flows.nodered.org/flow/1d89b384a115338e8a210d49ee474cfb) , that doesn't use extra nodes. But all these examples either require a MQTT topic in the configuration (which I don't know, and I see no way to figure out where to configure the topic and broker), or I have to provide an I2C "command" (besides the I2C Address which I know).

node-red runs on my Raspberry Pi, where I also have a mosquitto MQTT broker running.

It would be nice if anybody could help me in figuring out on how to access my sensor from node-red, using any types of nodes.
Of course MQTT would be preferred over using I2C directly.

Comment: Ever figured it out?